# Keeping the service running indefinitely

Tags: android, android-intent, service, notifications

I'm trying to write a service that will run in background until removed by the user, I used this code:

```
    Intent activityIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
            activityIntent, 0);

    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this).
            setContentTitle(getText(R.string.app_name)).
            setContentText("Doing stuff").
            setContentInfo("").
            setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon).
            setDeleteIntent(createOnDismissedIntent(getBaseContext(), notId)).
            setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();



    notificationManager.notify(notId,notification);

    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
```

The service is supposed to listen for incoming SMS and then do something once it detects an SMS.
Now it works , But if I wait for a little while and then try sending myself an SMS to see if the service is still up , the service does not do any thing implying that the service is down(I think), So my question is , Why would the service be down if i used 'START_REDELIVER_INTENT'? 
-I remove the notification in onDestroy function in the service. So while the service stops working after a while the notification is still there implying that the service has not been destroyed

Comment: A Service can be killed at any time to make room for other apps. The system will try to restart it eventually, but you'll have to handle scenarios where it won't be available.

Answer (score 1):

You need autorestart service after reboot.

Manifest:

```
<service android:exported="false" android:name=".service.YourService" android:enabled="true"></service>
  <receiver android:name=".service.YourBootReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
      </intent-filter>
```

Also permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Define receiver:

```
public class YourBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(arg0, YourService.class);
        arg0.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But my main question was why would the service stop after a while ?

Comment: I will check youtr code later, but mine i use and its ok, my service is working always.